# VS Team Services Project Dependency Build

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure-devops

I am new to Team Services (web based) build process. I have a Solution 1 with Project A and B where B is dependent on A (common code). Project A is under a different Solution 2 but was added to Solution 1 via "Add...Existing Project". Both solutions and projects are under TS source control. When I checked in Project B, Team Services build process could not find Project A and the build failed. How do I link Project A to the build process for Solution 1/Project B? Is there a better way to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the folders’ structure, for example:

1. Open solution file through NotePad and check the path of Project A (e.g. `..\solution1\ProjectA\ProjectA.csproj`)
2. Edit your build definition add Project A in workspace mapping (Get sources), for example:

(Server path=>local path)

```
[solution 2 server path] => solution2

[solution 1 server path] => solution1
```

Comment: So I am not sure I understand what this means. In my sln file I have these lines - SccProjectUniqueName3 = ..\\Solution1\\ProjectA\\ProjectA.csproj
SccProjectName3 = ../../Solution1/ProjectA/ProjectA
SccLocalPath3 = ..\\Solution1\\ProjectA What do I need to change?

Comment: @Joe ..\\Solution1\\ProjectA\\ProjectA.cspro is the relative path, you can check it in Project section (e.g. Project("{XXX}")="ProjectA","[relative path]",xxx, EndProject. Then the workspace mapping like this $/[teamproject]/[Solution2 path] => Solution2; $/[teamproject]/[Solution1 path]=> solution1

Comment: Oh my, thank you for the help, I actually got it working! I had to play with setting up the local path by looking at the failed build (had to append the Solution 1/Project B path) but the key was the $/teamproject. I looked at it and figured out.